# Cannot pass list of objects from view to controller by Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I cannot pass a list of objects to a controller via Ajax.

However my code is simple :

Here is the object class :

```
    public class OptionDTO
{

    public string ID_OPTION { get; set; }       
    public string LI_VALUE { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my view :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="divOption">

<table id="TableOption">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <tr class="item">
        <td>@item.LI_OPTION</td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" class="option-value" data-id="@item.ID_OPTION" />
        </td>
    </tr>
   }
</table>
```

```
<script>

function fctValidate() {
    var lstOption = [];
    try
    {
        $(".option-value").each(function(){
            var oOption = new Object();
            oOption.ID_OPTION = $(this).attr('data-id');
            oOption.LI_VALUE = $(this).val();
            lstOption.push(oOption);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOption", "CreateOption")',
        data: { "lstOption": lstOption },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreateOption(List<OptionDTO> lstOption)
{
   string dd = "";
}
```

I fill the input "text" with values (several rows in the table).
I have checked in the javascript that the list contains several rows.
And when I click on the Validation button the code goes to the controller but the parameter lstOption remains empty.

Could you help me, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Eric.

Comment: in the view, what are you using as model?

Comment: Just going on a guess here : instead of `data: { "lstOption": lstOption }` try - `data: lstOption `

Comment: There is no `LI_OPTION` in the class `OptionDTO` you showed us. So above view should raise an error on `<td>@item.LI_OPTION</td>`.

Comment: derloopkat, Dawood Awan : thank you for your answers.
I will check them and I will let you know.

Answer (score -1):

derloopkat, Dawood Awan :
Thanks to your advices, I finally have the solution which works :

```
 function fctValidate() {
    var lstOption = [];
    try {
        $(".option-value").each(function () {
            lstOption.push({
                ID_OPTION: $(this).data('id'),
                LI_VALUE: $(this).val()

            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateOption", "CreateOption")',
        data: { 'lstOption': lstOption },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
```